# How do I copy a DB from the server to the application's AppData folder?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005, mdf, appdata

I've been working on an ASP.NET application accessing a DB in my local machine.
Now I want to have this DB in the app's AppData folder instead, so I can easily work on it from within VS SQL instance accessing the mdf file, and easily copy and share it between programmers.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use SSMS to detach your database.

Next, find the MDF and LDF files for your database.  They should be in:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data
```

Copy those files to your App_Data folder.

If you want to switch to using SQL Express, then change your connection string to point to the MDF file. If you want to continue using SQL Developer / etc, then use SSMS to re-attach the MDF and LDF from their new location.

I guess I should add that this usually isn't a good idea, but I assume you have your reasons.

Comment: I know it's a bad idea, but when you have a small simple database you want to email in 1 zip file in your project that the other developer doesn't have to execute scripts and "hey, where do i download smss?" etc. etc. that's the the best idea, is this unusual, i can live with it...